# How do I I do nodejs HTTP requests one after the other?

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I've got a bunch of HTTP requests I need to send to a web service one after the other. I don't want to run them concurrently because I'll get in trouble for running that many simultaneous queries against the service.

I thought I could do this with await and an async function but it seems like it's still not waiting for one request to finish before the other. If I run the code below all 50 requests get fired as fast as my computer can send them...

Am I just using promises wrong? Is there a better way to do this? I'm just shy of falling back on writing CURL command :P.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const [, , ...args] = process.argv
const request = require('request'); 

const fs = require('fs');

function downloadReport(options){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    console.log("Sending request at " + new Date() );

    request(options, function(error,response,body){

        if (error) reject(error);

        console.log("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        console.log("options is " + JSON.stringify (options));
        console.log("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        console.log("Request Complete at " + new Date() );

        resolve(body);

    });

    });

}//END FUNCTION DOWNLOAD REPORT

async function pullReport(options){

        console.log("report pull for " + options.i);

        try{

            var body = await downloadReport(options);

            console.log("Writing out " + options.i + " - report.txt\r\n");
            console.log("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

            fs.writeFile(options.i + " - report.txt", body, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                }       
            });


        }catch(ex){
            console.error('ERROR:');
            console.error(ex);
        }

}//END PULLREPORT FUNCTION

process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;

const url = "https://www.google.com"

for (var i = 1; i<=50;i++){

    var options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,       
            i:i
    };

    console.log("***********************************************************************************************");
    pullReport(options); 
    console.log("***********************************************************************************************");


}//END FOR LOOP
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you just need to `await pullReport(options);` in your loop:

```js
(async function main() {
  try {
    for (var i = 1; i<=50; i++){

        var options = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: url,
                i:i
        };

        console.log("***********************************************************************************************");
        await pullReport(options);
        console.log("***********************************************************************************************");


    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Yes! That's it. That's the part I was missing/misunderstanding. Thanks!